# What kind of trivial statement still needs to be proven?

Tags: proof-theory

There are many statements that seem to be needless of a proof since they are ‘evident’ mainly because of our intuition. But some of them have proofs. For example, in C. Adams’ Introduction to topology, the Jordan Curve Theorem has a 3-page proof but the same book says, “**clearly** $\mathbb{R}^n$ is path connected, as is every open ball and every closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$" (i.e., no need to prove).

Please note that the mentioned two statements above are just examples to explain what I mean by the main question: How trivial is something trivial?

Comment: I would think it is all relative to what topic is at hand, the context of the proof, and the targeted audience. Thus you will probably not get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @AlphaE: [Theorems that are 'obvious' but hard to prove, mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/51531/73786) and $1+1=2$ among those :)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer, but too long to be a comment:

---

Your example actually isn't very good. The book says:

> Clearly, every open ball in $\mathbb R^n$ is path connected.

This is truly a trivial statement, since every open ball in $\mathbb R^n$ is *convex*, and thus path connected.

---

The Jordan curve theorem, on the other hand, claims:

> If $Y$ is an image of an injective continuous mapping from $S^{n}$ to $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Then, $\mathbb R^{n+1}\setminus Y$ consists of two path connected components, of which one is bounded and the other is not. $Y$ is the edge of both components.

It's quite clear that this theorem is **not** equivalent to just saying "every open ball in $\mathbb R^n$ is path connected". In fact, this is a much stronger claim!

That said, of course there are simple statements that have never been proven. For example, the famous Goldbach conjecture is a simple example of a very simple statement that has not yet been proven:

> Every positive even number is the sum of two prime numbers.

Comment: Is there any proof for the statement "every convex open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is path connected"?

Comment: Of course there is, and it was probably written down thousands of times by math students all over the world: Take $x,y\in C$ where $C$ is a convec set. Then, $\gamma(t) = (1-t)x + ty$ is a path from $x$ to $y$, therefore, $C$ is path connected.